# How to set fixed table width(not cell) in table sorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I use table sorter. According the table content different pages(pagination) can have different width.

Thus if scroll pages it looks enough ugly.

Is it possible to set fixed table width. ratio of table column width can be change in different pages.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5274)

source:

html:

```
<!-- pager --> 
<div class="pager"> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/> 
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input --> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/> 
        <select class="pagesize" title="Select page size"> 
            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option> 
            <option value="20">20</option> 
            <option value="30">30</option> 
            <option value="40">40</option> 
        </select>
        <select class="gotoPage" title="Select page number"></select>
</div>

<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Japanese</th>
            <th>Calculus</th>
            <th>Geometry</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Major</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>English</th>
            <th>Japanese</th>
            <th>Calculus</th>
            <th>Geometry</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Student01111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student02</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student03</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student04</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>60</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student05</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>68</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student06</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>99</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student07</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>68</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student08</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student09</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>65</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student10</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student11</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>86</td>
            <td>85</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student12</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>75</td>
            <td>70</td>
            <td>85</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student13</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student14</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student15</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>95</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student16</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student17</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>female</td>
            <td>80</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>65</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student18</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>49</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>75</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student19</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>68</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>88</td>
            <td>70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student20</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student21</td>
            <td>Languages</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Student22</td>
            <td>Mathematics</td>
            <td>male</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>99</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>Student23</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>82</td><td>77</td><td>0</td><td>79</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student24</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>100</td><td>91</td><td>13</td><td>82</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student25</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>22</td><td>96</td><td>82</td><td>53</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student26</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>37</td><td>29</td><td>56</td><td>59</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student27</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>86</td><td>82</td><td>69</td><td>23</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student28</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>44</td><td>25</td><td>43</td><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student29</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>77</td><td>47</td><td>22</td><td>38</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student30</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>19</td><td>35</td><td>23</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student31</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>90</td><td>27</td><td>17</td><td>50</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student32</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>60</td><td>75</td><td>33</td><td>38</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student33</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>4</td><td>31</td><td>37</td><td>15</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student34</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>77</td><td>97</td><td>81</td><td>44</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student35</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>5</td><td>81</td><td>51</td><td>95</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student36</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>70</td><td>61</td><td>70</td><td>94</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student37</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>60</td><td>3</td><td>61</td><td>84</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student38</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>63</td><td>39</td><td>0</td><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student39</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>50</td><td>46</td><td>32</td><td>38</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student40</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>51</td><td>75</td><td>25</td><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student41</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>43</td><td>34</td><td>28</td><td>78</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student42</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>11</td><td>89</td><td>60</td><td>95</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student43</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>48</td><td>92</td><td>18</td><td>88</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student44</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>82</td><td>2</td><td>59</td><td>73</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student45</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>91</td><td>73</td><td>37</td><td>39</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student46</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>4</td><td>8</td><td>12</td><td>10</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student47</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>89</td><td>10</td><td>6</td><td>11</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student48</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>90</td><td>32</td><td>21</td><td>18</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student49</td><td>Mathematics</td><td>male</td><td>42</td><td>49</td><td>49</td><td>72</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Student50</td><td>Languages</td><td>female</td><td>56</td><td>37</td><td>67</td><td>54</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<!-- pager --> 
<div class="pager"> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/first.png" class="first"/> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/prev.png" class="prev"/> 
        <span class="pagedisplay"></span> <!-- this can be any element, including an input --> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/next.png" class="next"/> 
        <img src="http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/addons/pager/icons/last.png" class="last"/> 
        <select class="pagesize" title="Select page size"> 
            <option selected="selected" value="10">10</option> 
            <option value="20">20</option> 
            <option value="30">30</option> 
            <option value="40">40</option> 
        </select>  
        <select class="gotoPage" title="Select page number"></select>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // *** APPEARANCE ***
    // Add a theme - try 'blackice', 'blue', 'dark', 'default'
    //  'dropbox', 'green', 'grey' or 'ice'
    // to use 'bootstrap' or 'jui', you'll need to add the "uitheme"
    // widget and also set it to the same name
    // this option only adds a table class name "tablesorter-{theme}"
    theme: 'blackice',

    // fix the column widths
    widthFixed: false,

    // Show an indeterminate timer icon in the header when the table
    // is sorted or filtered
    showProcessing: false,

    // header layout template (HTML ok); {content} = innerHTML,
    // {icon} = <i/> (class from cssIcon)
    headerTemplate: '{content}',

    // return the modified template string
    onRenderTemplate: null, // function(index, template){ return template; },

    // called after each header cell is rendered, use index to target the column
    // customize header HTML
    onRenderHeader: function (index) {
        // the span wrapper is added by default
        $(this).find('div.tablesorter-header-inner').addClass('roundedCorners');
    },

    // *** FUNCTIONALITY ***
    // prevent text selection in header
    cancelSelection: true,

    // other options: "ddmmyyyy" & "yyyymmdd"
    dateFormat: "mmddyyyy",

    // The key used to select more than one column for multi-column
    // sorting.
    sortMultiSortKey: "shiftKey",

    // key used to remove sorting on a column
    sortResetKey: 'ctrlKey',

    // false for German "1.234.567,89" or French "1 234 567,89"
    usNumberFormat: true,

    // If true, parsing of all table cell data will be delayed
    // until the user initializes a sort
    delayInit: false,

    // if true, server-side sorting should be performed because
    // client-side sorting will be disabled, but the ui and events
    // will still be used.
    serverSideSorting: false,

    // *** SORT OPTIONS ***
    // These are detected by default,
    // but you can change or disable them
    // these can also be set using data-attributes or class names
    headers: {
        // set "sorter : false" (no quotes) to disable the column
        0: {
            sorter: "text"
        },
        1: {
            sorter: "digit"
        },
        2: {
            sorter: "text"
        },
        3: {
            sorter: "url"
        }
    },

    // ignore case while sorting
    ignoreCase: true,

    // forces the user to have this/these column(s) sorted first
    sortForce: null,
    // initial sort order of the columns, example sortList: [[0,0],[1,0]],
    // [[columnIndex, sortDirection], ... ]
    sortList: [
        [0, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [2, 0]
    ],
    // default sort that is added to the end of the users sort
    // selection.
    sortAppend: null,

    // starting sort direction "asc" or "desc"
    sortInitialOrder: "asc",

    // Replace equivalent character (accented characters) to allow
    // for alphanumeric sorting
    sortLocaleCompare: false,

    // third click on the header will reset column to default - unsorted
    sortReset: false,

    // restart sort to "sortInitialOrder" when clicking on previously
    // unsorted columns
    sortRestart: false,

    // sort empty cell to bottom, top, none, zero
    emptyTo: "bottom",

    // sort strings in numerical column as max, min, top, bottom, zero
    stringTo: "max",

    // extract text from the table - this is how is
    // it done by default
    textExtraction: {
        0: function (node) {
            return $(node).text();
        },
        1: function (node) {
            return $(node).text();
        }
    },

    // use custom text sorter
    // function(a,b){ return a.sort(b); } // basic sort
    textSorter: null,

    // *** WIDGETS ***

    // apply widgets on tablesorter initialization
    initWidgets: true,

    // include zebra and any other widgets, options:
    // 'columns', 'filter', 'stickyHeaders' & 'resizable'
    // 'uitheme' is another widget, but requires loading
    // a different skin and a jQuery UI theme.
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],

    widgetOptions: {

        // zebra widget: adding zebra striping, using content and
        // default styles - the ui css removes the background
        // from default even and odd class names included for this
        // demo to allow switching themes
        // [ "even", "odd" ]
        zebra: [
            "ui-widget-content even",
            "ui-state-default odd"],

        // uitheme widget: * Updated! in tablesorter v2.4 **
        // Instead of the array of icon class names, this option now
        // contains the name of the theme. Currently jQuery UI ("jui")
        // and Bootstrap ("bootstrap") themes are supported. To modify
        // the class names used, extend from the themes variable
        // look for the "$.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui" code below
        uitheme: 'jui',

        // columns widget: change the default column class names
        // primary is the 1st column sorted, secondary is the 2nd, etc
        columns: [
            "primary",
            "secondary",
            "tertiary"],

        // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
        // option will also be added to the table tfoot.
        columns_tfoot: true,

        // columns widget: If true, the class names from the columns
        // option will also be added to the table thead.
        columns_thead: true,

        // filter widget: If there are child rows in the table (rows with
        // class name from "cssChildRow" option) and this option is true
        // and a match is found anywhere in the child row, then it will make
        // that row visible; default is false
        filter_childRows: false,

        // filter widget: If true, a filter will be added to the top of
        // each table column.
        filter_columnFilters: true,

        // filter widget: css class applied to the table row containing the
        // filters & the inputs within that row
        filter_cssFilter: "tablesorter-filter",

        // filter widget: Customize the filter widget by adding a select
        // dropdown with content, custom options or custom filter functions
        // see http://goo.gl/HQQLW for more details
        filter_functions: null,

        // filter widget: Set this option to true to hide the filter row
        // initially. The rows is revealed by hovering over the filter
        // row or giving any filter input/select focus.
        filter_hideFilters: false,

        // filter widget: Set this option to false to keep the searches
        // case sensitive
        filter_ignoreCase: true,

        // filter widget: jQuery selector string of an element used to
        // reset the filters.
        filter_reset: null,

        // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching;
        // This option prevents searching for every character while typing
        // and should make searching large tables faster.
        filter_searchDelay: 300,

        // Set this option to true if filtering is performed on the server-side.
        filter_serversideFiltering: false,

        // filter widget: Set this option to true to use the filter to find
        // text from the start of the column. So typing in "a" will find
        // "albert" but not "frank", both have a's; default is false
        filter_startsWith: false,

        // filter widget: If true, ALL filter searches will only use parsed
        // data. To only use parsed data in specific columns, set this option
        // to false and add class name "filter-parsed" to the header
        filter_useParsedData: false,

        // Resizable widget: If this option is set to false, resized column
        // widths will not be saved. Previous saved values will be restored
        // on page reload
        resizable: true,

        // saveSort widget: If this option is set to false, new sorts will
        // not be saved. Any previous saved sort will be restored on page
        // reload.
        saveSort: true,

        // stickyHeaders widget: css class name applied to the sticky header
        stickyHeaders: "tablesorter-stickyHeader"

    },

    // *** CALLBACKS ***
    // function called after tablesorter has completed initialization
    initialized: function (table) {},

    // *** CSS CLASS NAMES ***
    tableClass: 'tablesorter',
    cssAsc: "tablesorter-headerSortUp",
    cssDesc: "tablesorter-headerSortDown",
    cssHeader: "tablesorter-header",
    cssHeaderRow: "tablesorter-headerRow",
    cssIcon: "tablesorter-icon",
    cssChildRow: "tablesorter-childRow",
    cssInfoBlock: "tablesorter-infoOnly",
    cssProcessing: "tablesorter-processing",

    // *** SELECTORS ***
    // jQuery selectors used to find the header cells.
    selectorHeaders: '> thead th, > thead td',

    // jQuery selector of content within selectorHeaders
    // that is clickable to trigger a sort.
    selectorSort: "th, td",

    // rows with this class name will be removed automatically
    // before updating the table cache - used by "update",
    // "addRows" and "appendCache"
    selectorRemove: "tr.remove-me",

    // *** DEBUGING ***
    // send messages to console
    debug: false

}).tablesorterPager({

    // target the pager markup - see the HTML block below
    container: $(".pager"),

    // use this url format "http:/mydatabase.com?page={page}&size={size}" 
    ajaxUrl: null,

    // process ajax so that the data object is returned along with the
    // total number of rows; example:
    // {
    //   "data" : [{ "ID": 1, "Name": "Foo", "Last": "Bar" }],
    //   "total_rows" : 100 
    // } 
    ajaxProcessing: function(ajax) {
        if (ajax && ajax.hasOwnProperty('data')) {
            // return [ "data", "total_rows" ]; 
            return [ajax.data, ajax.total_rows];
        }
    },

    // output string - default is '{page}/{totalPages}';
    // possible variables:
    // {page}, {totalPages}, {startRow}, {endRow} and {totalRows}
    output: '{startRow} to {endRow} ({totalRows})',

    // apply disabled classname to the pager arrows when the rows at
    // either extreme is visible - default is true
    updateArrows: true,

    // starting page of the pager (zero based index)
    page: 0,

    // Number of visible rows - default is 10
    size: 10,

    // if true, the table will remain the same height no matter how many
    // records are displayed. The space is made up by an empty 
    // table row set to a height to compensate; default is false 
    fixedHeight: true,

    // remove rows from the table to speed up the sort of large tables.
    // setting this to false, only hides the non-visible rows; needed
    // if you plan to add/remove rows with the pager enabled.
    removeRows: false,

    // css class names of pager arrows
    // next page arrow
    cssNext: '.next',
    // previous page arrow
    cssPrev: '.prev',
    // go to first page arrow
    cssFirst: '.first',
    // go to last page arrow
    cssLast: '.last',
    // select dropdown to allow choosing a page
    cssGoto: '.gotoPage',
    // location of where the "output" is displayed
    cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
    // dropdown that sets the "size" option
    cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
    // class added to arrows when at the extremes 
    // (i.e. prev/first arrows are "disabled" when on the first page)
    // Note there is no period "." in front of this class name
    cssDisabled: 'disabled'

});

// Extend the themes to change any of the default class names ** NEW **
$.extend($.tablesorter.themes.jui, {
    // change default jQuery uitheme icons - find the full list of icons
    // here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ (hover over them for their name)
    table: 'ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all', // table classes
    header: 'ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-state-default', // header classes
    icons: 'ui-icon', // icon class added to the <i> in the header
    sortNone: 'ui-icon-carat-2-n-s',
    sortAsc: 'ui-icon-carat-1-n',
    sortDesc: 'ui-icon-carat-1-s',
    active: 'ui-state-active', // applied when column is sorted
    hover: 'ui-state-hover', // hover class
    filterRow: '',
    even: 'ui-widget-content', // even row zebra striping
    odd: 'ui-state-default' // odd row zebra striping
});
```

Comment: Where is the code displaying the scenario ?

Comment: @Mayank http://jsfiddle.net/4mVfu/5274/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few choices

- Use css3 `text-overflow: ellipsis;` ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow) & [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/5279/)):

  ```
  td {
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
  ```

  The main issue with this would be the overflowed text would be hidden, so if you want the user to be able to read all the text, one idea would be to add it to the `td`'s `title` attribute.
- Or, use css3 `word-break: break-all` ([browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break) & [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4mVfu/5280/)):

  ```
  td {
    max-width: 100px;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
  ```

  The main issue with this method is text in other cells may break in the middle of a word instead of at a space.

Adjust the `max-width` as desired.

Comment: A title attribute based tooltip:  jQuery Overflow Tooltip https://github.com/mitchogaard/jquery-overflow-tooltip